# how to refer another view from the current one?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I'm struggling with a very basic feature. I want to refer another view from the current view to load the content from that view by applying very basic ajax. here is the code:

```
<div>
    <ul id="biographies">
    <li> <a href="Ajax">Ajax</a></li>
    <li> <a href="Index">Index</a>  </li>

    </ul>    

    <div id="biography">
      The ajax content will appear here...
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#biography").load('Ajax.cshtml');


    </script>

</div>
```

Both the page is in the same directory that is: views/home

- Question 1: how to pass the parameter for load event?
- Question 2: how to link to other pages using the anchor tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504960%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper method:

```
$("#biography").load('@Url.Action("Ajax")');
```

Similarly, you can use [`Html.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493018%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to get an `a` tag for actions or routes:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go to Index", "Index")

@Html.ActionLink("Go to Home:Index", "Index", "About")
```

The output will be like `<a href='/About/Index'>Go to Home:Index</a>`.

Remember, with MVC the idea is that URLs point to resources and routes, not to specific files.  It's best to use these helper methods (rather than writing out hard-coded URLs) as they specify the route precisely.

Comment: Note: this will be the address to an action, not to a view. Ie, you'll need an action to serve your view.

Comment: tried the url.action method as the parameter of the load event but still its not working! Anything else to do?

Comment: @Jobskuk did you note Onkelborg's comment?  There needs to be an action named `Ajax` as well as the view.

Comment: @Jobskuk the URL for the `Ajax` view in the `Home` controller should normally be `/Home/Ajax`.

Comment: I have the action method for Ajax, no problem with that. but it seems the load event is not firing!

Comment: No, I was wrong, the load event is ok, I have just checked with an alert statement! but it can't load the element from ajax page. As far I know the contents within the body tag on ajax page should be shown here, isn't it?

Comment: @Jobskuk 1. verify the `Ajax` page loads by itself - navigate to `/Home/Ajax`.  2. Are you sure `load` is working? I don't see how an `alert` statement would allow you to verify that.

Comment: I just put an alert statement as the parameter of load event & it showed. Ajax page is loading fine when I'm clicking on the link above but not with the load event. Anyway thanks for your effort mate, so nice of you.

Comment: @Jobskuk no prob, sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Its OK, if I can find it out, I will share here.

Comment: The problem is I didn't reference the jquery library correctly! Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Html.ActionLink` to generate links and then use jquery for ajax loading. Off course, you need to write actions in controller for returning partial views. Jquery code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzPDT/2/)